# EF Code First Cyclical Reference

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have a series of objects that represent folders and files. Folders can have a collection of files of course, but they can also have sub-folders. Folder has a reference back to the parent folder. This is probably where the trouble is starting. Also a folder can have an icon associated with it.

```
public class Folder
{
    [Key]
    public int FolderId { get; set; }
    public string FolderName { get; set; }
    public int ParentFolderId { get; set; }
    public virtual Folder ParentFolder { get; set; }
    public int IconId { get; set; }
    public virtual Icon Icon { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<FileInformation> FileInformations { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Folder> Folders { get; set; }
}

public class Icon
{
    [Key]
    public int IconId { get; set; }
    public string IconUrl { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

When I run the application and try to get a list of the icons however, I get this error message:

***The referential relationship will result in a cyclical reference that is not allowed. [ Constraint name = FK_Folder_Icon_IconId ]***

I'm not 100% where the circular reference is here. Folder only references Icon once, and Icon doesn't reference folder at all.

One problem, and this may be related, is that I'm not sure how to make ParentFolderId map back to the FolderId of the parent folder correctly.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do the FileInformations get involved in this in any way? I don't get a cyclical reference with the code you show.

Comment: are you doing any fluent configuration apart from this?

Comment: Have you found an answer? I'm facing a similar scenario.

Comment: I eventually resolved this simply by using the code-first "reverse engineering" tool. http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/72a60b14-1581-4b9b-89f2-846072eff19d

Answer (score 0):

Hi change Id instead of FolderId, IconId which are modified with [key]. Because you don't use mapping fluent code, and EF can only supposed relations with names and types.

It is working.

```
public class Folder
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string FolderName { get; set; }
    public virtual int ParentId { get; set; } /*ParentFolderId*/
    public virtual Folder Parent { get; set; } /*ParentFolder*/
    public virtual int IconId { get; set; }
    public virtual Icon Icon { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Folder> Children { get; set; } /*not Folders*/

   //it is out of subject 
   //public virtual ICollection<FileInformation> FileInformations { get; // set; }
}

public class Icon
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string IconUrl { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```